# kali linux 2020.3 Gui Problem

Tags: kali-linux

[image]

```
TigerVNC Viewer 32-bit v1.10.80
Built on: 2020-06-15 22:33
Copyright (C) 1999-2020 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.

Thu Aug 20 09:33:24 2020
 DecodeManager: Detected 4 CPU core(s)
 DecodeManager: Creating 4 decoder thread(s)

Thu Aug 20 09:33:26 2020
 CConn:       unable to connect to socket: No connection could be made because
              the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today: although it was working fine the other day, today it showed me the same exact errors you are facing.

I played around to get it working again by removing it and reinstalling it. When you remove it use this command

```
sudo apt-get purge kali-win-kex
```

and reinstall it like this

```
sudo apt reinstall kali-win-kex
```

Hope it helps!